# how to efficiently draw many interactive curves in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, svg, html5-canvas, curves

I need the ability to efficiently draw a large number of interactive curves (possibly Bezier) in a web app. Imagine a graph-like structure with many draggable elements that are connected with smooth curves. Hence, the curves must adjust in shape and length as single elements are moved.

What graphic method will be best to assure efficiency and interactivity for a large number curves?

SVG? Canvas? something else?

(And once we know which method is best, is there a good library that would make it easier to implement?)

Comment: Probably to best current library for thisL http://raphaeljs.com/

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at [JSXGraph](http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de). I haven't personally used it, but know some who has with nice results. It looks like it will use 'SVG, VML or canvas'.